# how to wrap many lines to 1 function on codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have codeigniter controller like below

```
    public function profil1()
{
    // **start-same-code**
    $this->is_logged_in();
    $varLogin = $this->session->userdata('login1');
    $varLoginData = $this->m_master_table->geIDDataUmum($varLogin['data'][0]->iduser);
    $varIdUser = '';
    $varIdUser = $varLoginData['iduser'];
    $data['varLoginData'] = $varLoginData;
    $data['varIdUser'] = $varIdUser;

    $modul = $varLoginData['modul'];
    $data['kd_jenis_usaha'] = $varLoginData['kd_jenis_usaha'];
    $data['namaJenisUsaha'] = $this->m_klasifikasi_usaha->getNamaJenisUsaha($varLoginData['kd_jenis_usaha']);
    $data['lstPengurus'] = $this->m_master_table->showAllPengurus_byIdUser($varIdUser);
    // **end-same-code**.   

    $data['page'] = 'pages/master_data/v_master_data_profil1';
    $this->load->view($this->template, $data);
}
```

How to wrap the same codes ("code-start to code-end") above to function for the next function below?

```
public function profil2(){ 

    // **same code here** 

    data['page'] = 'pages/master_data/v_master_data_profil2'; 
    $this->load->view($this->template, $data); 
}
```

Comment: Put it in another method and call that method when needed.